# Search and Replace from Excel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing some code in Visual Studio Code and want to place some variables there, which I replace with content from an Excel file.

For example:

```html
  <div class="column">
    VAR1
  </div>
```

Now I want to replace "VAR1" with the content from cell B3 in the Excel file "Test.xlsx".

Can I do this somehow with Visual Studio code or should I use some other way? And when so, can you please help me which way / point me in the right direction?

I am kinda lost and do not even know which is a proper search term for this, because when I use google I find very different things, so I guess I am thinking about this from a very wrong angle.

Comment: Could you provide more information on what you're trying to do and what programming languages you're using? This isn't a VSCode specific question. The small example you've given looks like pure HTML with the data from the Excel file being used as content to display.   It is possible to load Excel data and display it but you'll need to add in another layer such as JavaScript or some other backend (ex: using Flask library in Python) to load and generate the content. Depending on your end goal, some methods may be more appropriate than others.

Comment: write a Python script that reads Excel files and use your typed file as a template

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I use Hugo to build a website and there I use HTML code in a markdown file (.md). So, since you both recommend Python, I think I will go in that direction and see if I can make it work there. Thank you :)

Comment: do you want this "replacement" to be soft or hard? soft -> not actually modify the contents of the file, but display the file in the VS Code editor with the text replaced visually. hard -> actually modify the contents of the file in a way that will be saved to the filesystem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.